# Why does NDSolve return the stiff system error in this case?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I was playing with the `WhenEvent` method of `NDSolve` and was simulating the dynamics of a spring-mass system with two degrees-of-freedom (EDO: $M\ddot x+Kx=0$). `WhenEvent` was used to simulate an obstacle with a coefficient of restitution `e` (the velocity after impact is `-e` times the velocity before impact).

This works perfectly well, however when `e=0`, it returns the stiff system suspected error. I can't understand what's so special when `e=0`, on the contrary I would have thought this was the simplest case from a numerical point of view.

Full code (change to `e=0` to get the error):

```
m = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}];
k = {{2, -1}, {-1, 1}};
eqs = Thread[m.{x1''[t], x2''[t]} + k.{x1[t], x2[t]} == 0];
ics = {x1[0] == -1, x1'[0] == 0, x2[0] == -0.5, x2'[0] == 1};
e = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[
   eqs~Join~ics~
    Join~{WhenEvent[x2[t] == 1, x2'[t] -> -e*x2'[t]]}, {x1, x2}, {t, 
    0, 20}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], 1} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Didn't yet have the time to solve this using `ParametricNDSolve` but it would seem that your solution for `x2'[t]` as the value of your parameter `e` is decreased, forms some sort of a singularity.  Singularities can be associated with stiffness.  Also, does your solution tends to unstable oscillations as `e>2` or so?

Comment: @drN Seen from the mechanical standpoint: `e>1` means at each "bounce", the kinetic energy increases, so it should be unstable. For `e=1` the energy should be conserved (the time integration might dissipate some of it numerically, however). For `e<1`, each bounce results in a loss of kinetic energy.

Comment: Does performing a parametric NDSolve such as this: `sol = ParametricNDSolve[
  eqs~Join~ics~
   Join~{WhenEvent[x2[t] == 1, x2'[t] -> -param*x2'[t]]}, {x1, 
   x2}, {t, 0, 20}, {param}]` help you determine the issue?  `Plot[Evaluate[Table[x2[param][t] /. sol, {param, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]], {t, 
  3, 20}]`

Comment: @drN I think I understood while I was explaining why your comment did not help :). I am going to write an answer.

Comment: so in essence, my comment helped... `>:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `e=0` means, from a mechanical standpoint, that the second mass looses all its kinetic energy everytime it reaches the obstacle. It also means there is a horizontal tangent at the position `x2[t]==1`, and that's what causes the singularity: the event is probably triggered at the time step following from the event, and refining the time step makes it even worse... and so on.

A workaround is to add a condition on the first derivative in `WhenEvent`:

```
sol = NDSolve[eqs~Join~ics~
   Join~{WhenEvent[x2[t] == 1 && x2'[t] > 0.000001, x2'[t] -> -e*x2'[t]]}, 
   {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 20}]
```